# «Есмы» – толкование этого слова

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Что имеется в виду под словом «есмы»?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Это форма первого лица множественного числа от глагола "быть" — *мы есть.* Используется в церковнославянском. Аналогично английскому *we are* или французскому *nous sommes.*

Answer (score 2):

Здесь требуется не толкование, а перевод.
***Есмы*** *(устар.)* — форма настоящего времени первого лица множественного числа изъявительного наклонения глагола **быть**. Возник в результате слияния слов *"есть"* и *"мы"*.

Пример:

> Отвѣща́ша [и рѣ́ша] Ему́: сѣ́мя Авраа́мле **есмы́**, и никому́же
> рабо́тахомъ николи́же: ка́ко Ты́ глаго́леши, я́ко свобо́дни бу́дете?
> (Ин 8:33)

Перевод (еп. Кассиана):

> Ответили они Ему: мы семя Авраамово, и никому не были рабами никогда.
> Как же Ты говоришь: «вы сделаетесь свободными»?

Поскольку в современном русском глагол *"есть"* практически не используется в сочетаниях типа "я есть Иван", "мы есть жильцы этого дома", то и здесь он опущен. Если бы он писался, фраза звучала бы так: *"Ответили они Ему: мы **есть** семя Авраамово..."*

Comment: Почему *мы есть,* если *есмы* форма как раз для множественного числа?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой потому что в современном русском языке нет аналога слова "есмы", а есть только "есть мы" или "мы есть", если без инверсии.